# Reemplazar links de css y js con el contenido de esos archivos?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy utilizando una plataforma en la cual puedo crear mis propios sitios, pero no solamente puedo escribir HTML, no tengo donde poner archivos CSS o JS.

Quisiera saber si existe algun plugin o alguna herramienta que pueda utilizar para que en lugar de tener los links a los archivos css y a los archivos js, se "incrusten" directamente en el html.

Ex:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Soy un titulo</h1>
    <p>soy un parrafo</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Se convierta en esto:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <title></title>
 <style>
  body, html{
   background: pink;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Soy un titulo</h1>
 <p>soy un parrafo</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Esto, asumiendo que en el archivo style.css solamente se encuentra la regla

```css
body, html{
            background: pink;
        }
```

En el caso de las imágenes si se pueden tener en el servidor, lo único con lo que tengo problemas es con el CSS y JS.

Comment: Un Plugin para una tarea simple como copiar los estilos en el html directamente no creo que sea buena idea. ¿Por qué no incrusta directamente de forma manual los estilos en el tag `style`?

Comment: Porque el HTML se está generando con Bootstrap Studio, y Bootstrap Studio genera los estilos en un archivo aparte. Lo que quiero hacer es, tomar el contenido de esos archivos aparte y meterlos en tags style

Comment: `@import "file.css";` 
 , o `PHP`  con  [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/es/function.file-get-contents.php).

Comment: Stacksnippet sólo debe usarse con código ejecutable en las páginas de preguntas/respuestas.

Comment: ¿Por qué no usar el tradicional copiar y pegar? Por otro lados las preguntas que incluyen "quisiera saber si existe algún lo que sea" dan pie a respuestas basadas en opiniones y este tipo de preguntas no son las que queremos en este sitio. Favor de seguir el [tour] y leer [ask].

Comment: Prueba subiendo los css y js a google drive.

Comment: La pregunta no es clara.. ¿Qué plataforma es? ¿Qué tipo de plugins buscas, en qué lenguaje se programan? Falta información para una respuesta concreta.

Comment: No entiendo ¿Si se generan los estilos en un archivo para qué quieres traerlo al HTML? Si necesitas modificar algo y no tienes acceso al CSS pon las reglas que necesites en el HTML pero ¿qué sentido tiene trasladar todo el css?

Answer (score 0):

usar php y hacer lo siguiente, si es style, incluir el archivo dentro de las etiqueta style del html, y si es script en la etiqueta script de html

```
<style>
<?php echo file_get_contents('css/style.css');
</style>
```